# Pure birth process - with gender

Tags: markov-chains, mathematical-modeling, birth-death-process

> A population of organisms consists of both male and female members. Any particular male is likely to mate with any particular female, in any time interval of length $h$, with probability $\lambda h + o(h)$. Each mating immediately produces one offspring, equally likely to be male or female. There are no deaths. Let $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ denote the number of males and females in the population at time $t$. This can be modeled as a continuous time Markov chain.
>
> (a) What is the state space?
>
> (b) What are the parameters $v_i$ and $P_{ij}$ (rate to leave the state $i$ and the probability that the jump is to $j$ when this happens)?
>
> (c) What do you think the limiting probabilities will be?

Here is my answer to the question but I am not really sure. Please let me know what you think.

(a) $S = \{(i,j)\}, i,j \in \mathbb{N_0}$ $i = N_1(t), j = N_2(t)$

(b) $v_i=\lambda$ only when $i\in \{(i,j)\}$, where both $i,j$  are positive integers.
$v_i=0$ otherwise.

$P_{ij}=1$

(c) If the starting state is one of {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)}, the limiting probability will be $P_{ii}=1$. Otherwise, limiting probability doesn't exists as $ N_1(t), N_2(t)$ can go to infinity.